# Creating bespoke permissions on an Excel file in a SP doc library

Tags: permissions

In SP2010 we have a document library containing an excel file. A number of users have contribute permissions on this library.

However, our users are now saying they want to restrict permissions. What they specifically want is one user who can edit, create and delete documents in the library whilst the remainder of users can edit the document but who are not able to create or delete documents.

The out-of-the-box permissions don't seem to offer this functionality. Is this possible at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible as you can create two SharePoint groups with custom permissions level, however you will have to go through some steps and have to be Site Administrator.

here's [Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on MSDN which illiterate how to create custom permissions levels

You can do it using UI

http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3911751/Implementing-ItemLevel-Security-in-SharePoint-2010-and-2007.htm

Or throw code,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253622/c-sharp-how-to-set-sharepoint-permissions-for-user-under-subsite-not-root-leve